# Convert date in MM/dd/yyyy format in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` and I m getting the selected date from it in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.Now I want to convert it to `MM/dd/yyyy` format ..How can i do it ?

```
NSDateFormatter *df=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSArray *temp=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:DatePicker.date]] componentsSeparatedByString:@""];

[dateString2 release];
dateString2=nil;
dateString2= [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[temp objectAtIndex:0]];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString2);
```

Im getting 2012-10-30 but I want 10/30/2012.

Comment: This isn't really to do with Xcode, it's to do with the Cocoa Touch framework.

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html Appendix F is your friend

Comment: Uh, change the date formatter format?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

See Instruction or introduction with every line

```
NSString *str = @"2012-10-30"; /// here this is your date with format yyyy-MM-dd

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; // here we create NSDateFormatter object for change the Format of date..
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; //// here set format of date which is in your output date (means above str with format)

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str]; // here you can fetch date from string with define format

dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];// here set format which you want...

NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; //here convert date in NSString
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

Comment: @HotLicks hey mate i just post this answer with instruction so any one easily understand whole flow so i just put this FLOW... :)

Comment: @HotLicks Because the original question originated from a yyyy-MM-dd. This answer covers that. So please, if you down voted. Explain why.

Comment: @Da_smokes -- The original question originated from an NSDate coming from a UIDatePicker.

Answer (score 1):

df.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to see how it ends up:

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
df.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
NSString* dateString = [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date];  // Don't use leading caps on variables
NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The original accepted answer does a few things extra:

1) It allocates two NSDateFormatter instances which is not required. NSDateFormatter is expensive to create.

2) It is better to release date formatters explicitly when you are done with them rather than a deferred release using autorelease.

```
//get datepicker date (NSDate *)
NSDate *datePickerDate = [myDatePicker date];

//create a date formatter
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 

//set its format as the required output format
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

//get the output date as string
NSString *outputDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:datePickerDate];

//release formatter
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)showTime {
   NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
   // you label
   _time.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now]; 
}

- (void)showDate {
   NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
   // you label
   _date.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    self.showTime;
    self.showDate;
}
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"2012-10-30"; /// here this is your date with format yyyy-MM-dd

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; // here we create NSDateFormatter object for change the Format of date..
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; //// here set format of date which is in your output date (means above str with format)

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str]; // here you can fetch date from string with define format

dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];// here set format which you want...

NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; here convert date in NSString
NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a code with options NSISO8601DateFormatWithDashSeparatorInDate:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString * stringformat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMddy" options:NSISO8601DateFormatWithDashSeparatorInDate locale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:stringformat];

NSDate *d = [NSDate date]; // or set your date
NSLog(@"date in format %@",  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:d]); // date in format 2018-06-20
```