# How to Get Date, Hour, Minute and Second in Objective-c from Timestamp "2017-04-30T14:30+00:00(GMT)"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in iOS(Objective-c) coding and I'm stuck at timestamp.
I'm getting timestamp while JSON parsing ie.`2017-04-30T14:30+00:00(GMT)`. How to get date, hour, minute and second from this timestamp?? I'm getting this format in `GMT` so, is it possible to convert it into `"IST"`? How?

Comment: You want to change the locale I think this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7259553/6203030  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138957/convert-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-in-xcode

Comment: Thank you @AitorPagán for suggestion. That helped in converting timezone.

Comment: Bookmark this: http://nsdateformatter.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Date Format Patterns**
A date pattern is a string of characters, where specific strings of characters are replaced with date and time data from a calendar when formatting or used to generate data for a calendar when parsing. The following are the characters used in patterns to show the appropriate formats for a given locale. The following are examples:

[image]

```
- (NSString *)curentDateStringFromDate:(NSDate *)dateTimeInLine withFormat:(NSString *)dateFormat {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

    [formatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];

    NSString *convertedString = [formatter stringFromDate:dateTimeInLine];

    return convertedString;
}
```

Use it like below:

```
NSString *dateString = [self curentDateStringFromDate:[NSDate date] withFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *timeString = [self curentDateStringFromDate:[NSDate date] withFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *hoursString = [self curentDateStringFromDate:[NSDate date] withFormat:@"h"];
```

In the `Foundation framework`, the class to use for this task (in either direction) is `NSDateFormatter` [Refer here](https://oleb.net/blog/2011/11/working-with-date-and-time-in-cocoa-part-2/)

The code below convert GMT to IST.

```
NSString *inDateStr = @"2000/01/02 03:04:05";
NSString *s = @"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";

// about input date(GMT)
NSDateFormatter *inDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
inDateFormatter.dateFormat = s;
inDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSDate *inDate = [inDateFormatter dateFromString:inDateStr];

// about output date(IST)
NSDateFormatter *outDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
outDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"IST"];
outDateFormatter.dateFormat = s;
NSString *outDateStr = [outDateFormatter stringFromDate:inDate];

// final output
NSLog(@"[in]%@ -> [out]%@", inDateStr, outDateStr);
```

Comment: thanx for help @Suresh.D brother. GMT to IST is done thank you for help. but still my main question is that how can I get Date, Hours from that Timestamp. If I'll get help that would be big help.

Comment: @MaulikDesai updated my answer please go and check, Accept the answer if you got it. Thanks in Advance.